# Присваивание массиву символов элементов массива целых чисел (С#)

Tags: c#

У меня есть два массива: один состоит из чисел int[] С и другой из символов (пока пустой) char[] End. Как можно вообще "положить" элементы массива  С в массив End ? Пробовал End[i]=C[i];, но как преобразовать цифры из массива C в цифры-символы? Просто у меня массив End должен содержать цифры из массива C и кроме этого еще некоторые символы (пример, 145AB). AB получается добавить, а цифры никак.

Comment: End[0] = System.Convert.ToChar(A[0]);

Comment: допускается ли, что в массиве C лежит число < 0 или > 9? Или там только цифры будут лежать? Если ложит 12, то в массиве End это как должно выглядеть? `End = {'1', '2'}`?

Answer (score 1):

```cs
using System.Linq;

//.....

int[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

char[] charArray = intArray.Select(i => (char)(i + '0')).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", charArray)); //=> 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что это именно то, что вы хотите, но вот возможное решение:

```
var intArr = new int[] {4, 2, -2, 96};

var charList = new List<char>();
foreach (var number in intArr)
{
    var numberAsCharArr = number.ToString().ToCharArray();
    charList.AddRange(numberAsCharArr);
}

var charArr = charList.ToArray();
```

Здесь `intArr` - это ваш `int[] C`, а `charArr` - это `char[] End`